# date tz converts with GMT and City Names with same GMT get differ result

Tags: shell-script, conversion, timezone, data

I want convert custom string time on UTC between different time zones defined as GMT.

I general all answers that is here ok.
But some question is with this examples:

1.`TZ='GMT-07' date --date='TZ="UTC" 00:34'`

> 07:34:00 +0700

2.`TZ=':America/Vancouver' date --date='TZ="UTC" 00:34'`

> 17:34:00 -0700

Why differ result when I try use GMT for destination TZ?

This City have same GMT.

P.S. So I found solution with GMT destination on result by time and wrong TZ display.

```
TZ='UTC' date --date='TZ="GMT-07" 00:34'
```

> 17:34:00 +0000

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> TZ='GMT-07'
> TZ=':America/Vancouver'
> ```

The claim that these are the same is false.  The first one is a POSIX-style rule that describes a timezone (with the abbreviation "GMT") that is 7 hours *ahead* of UTC in standard time and that has no daylight savings time shift.  The negative number means *ahead* of UTC.

Vancouver is in the Pacific timezone and is 8 hours *behind* UTC in standard time and 7 hours behind it in daylight savings time.  The correct POSIX-style rule, simplifying the actual complexities of Canadian law as POSIX-style rules do, is `PST8PDT`.

## Further reading

- `man tzset`